# Ответ приходит в виде знаков вопроса , когда передаю кириллицу

Tags: java, spring, post, unicode

Подскажите, как вывести русские буквы. Присутствуют контролер , сервис , модель dto

Передаю post запрос в контролере , с двумя параметрами:

```
 @CrossOrigin
  @PostMapping("/go")
    public String showGeneralPage(@RequestParam(value = "token") String token,
            @RequestParam(value = "orderId") String orderId) throws  IOException {
    
    
        
        return instrumentGetService.getInfoError(token, orderId);
        
    }
```

Сервис:

```
 /* ****** код */



String sendEmail(Attribute attribute) throws  IOException {
            
              var to = "";
                var subject = "";
                var error = "";
                var copyTo = "mail@mail.ru";
                var message="";
                
                
                
                if (attribute.getCode() == 666 ) {
                    error = "666";
                    to = "mail@mail";
                    subject = "русский текст";
                  }
                else if (attribute.getCode() == 55) {
                    error = "55";
                    to = "mail@mail.ru";
                                      
                    switch(attribute.example.substring(2, 5)) {
                    
                    case "276" :
                        subject=" русский текст";
                        break;
                    case "277" :
                        subject="русский текст";
                        break;
                    case "278" :
                        subject="русский текст";
                        break;
                    case "279" :
                        subject="русский текст";
                        break;
                    default:
                        subject ="русский текст";
                        break;
                 }
                  }
                
                 message = "русский текст " + attribute.getDate() + "русский текст: " + String.valueOf(attribute.getExample())+
                        "ID: " + attribute.getExample()+ "русский текст: " + attribute.getExample()+"русский текст"+error +
                         " русский текст";
                 
                 var url = "mailto:" + to + "?cc=" + copyTo + "&subject=" + subject + "&body=" + message;
                 
                
                 
                 return url;
        }
```

Когда делаю запрос на postman мне приходит ответ в виде строки :

```
mailto:mail@mail.ru?cc=mail@mail.ru&subject=?????.&body=????????: Mon May 17 12:00:41 SAMT 2021???????: 3757ID: 23413?????: example??????666 ??????????? ???????.
```

Каким способом , можно передать русские буквы , что бы корректно все отображалось, а не знаки вопроса. Все уже пересмотрел в интернете , так и не нашел. Использую spring boot , maven

Логи из postman:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/go
200
843 ms
POST /go HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 333354db-8956-4cc3-8d14-d79e68548fd6
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 77
token=i9d4336jroul&orderId=ff484d3-c6fe-793a-9463-5c46ee25
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 210
Date: Sat, 22 May 2021 21:05:34 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Покажите логи запроса.

Comment: @RomanC а какие логи запроса, уточните пожалуйста  ? Не очень понимаю, просто ошибок в передачи нету, мне кажется , что компонентов не хватает каких то

Comment: Вы делаете запрос из postman? Там должны быть логи запроса, которые он пишет в консоль.

Comment: @RomanC я обновил свой вопрос. В конце.

Comment: Так у вас стоит кодировка `ISO-8859-1`, которая не имеет русских символов. Поставьте `UTF-8`.

Comment: @RomanC а где ее прописывать ? Если в самом коде , то это конфигурация должна быть или как то по-другому ?

Comment: @RomanC Спасибо Вам за подсказку, разобрался!

Comment: Указал в контролере @RequestMapping(value={"/go"}, method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")  и заработало